Escaping a regex in jsonnet
i am trying to get a literal regex ^sl1\.([a-z0-9_-]+)\.([a-z0-9_-]+)\.(data)+$ 1:1 from jsonnet to the kubernetes-manifest.
~> cat test.jsonnet
{
  topic_pattern: '^sl1\.([a-z0-9_-]+)\.([a-z0-9_-]+)\.(data)+$',
}

~> jsonnet test.jsonnet
STATIC ERROR: test.jsonnet:2:18-64: Unknown escape sequence in string literal: '.'



## with "\\":
~> cat test.jsonnet
{
  topic_pattern: '^sl1\\.([a-z0-9_-]+)\\.([a-z0-9_-]+)\\.(data)+$',
}

~> jsonnet test.jsonnet
{
   "topic_pattern": "^sl1\\.([a-z0-9_-]+)\\.([a-z0-9_-]+)\\.(data)+$"
}

Anyone have an idea how to get a single "" in the output?

Mind that the manifested "double-quoted" string does need the double slash escaping "\\.", to be valid, ie your 2nd example is actually valid, piping it to jq with raw output shows the expected single-slash string:
$ cat test.jsonnet
{
  topic_pattern: '^sl1\\.([a-z0-9_-]+)\\.([a-z0-9_-]+)\\.(data)+$',
}

# Filter field via `jq`
$ jsonnet test.jsonnet | jq .topic_pattern
"^sl1\\.([a-z0-9_-]+)\\.([a-z0-9_-]+)\\.(data)+$"

# Raw output
$ jsonnet test.jsonnet | jq -r .topic_pattern
^sl1\.([a-z0-9_-]+)\.([a-z0-9_-]+)\.(data)+$

A not so well-known syntax, is using @"..." to create verbatim strings, which voids the use of double backslash for this:
$ cat test-verbatim.jsonnet
{
  // NOTE: with the @"..." notation, you don't need to add double backslashes
  topic_pattern: @"^sl1\.([a-z0-9_-]+)\.([a-z0-9_-]+)\.(data)+$",
}

# Filter field via `jq`
$ jsonnet test-verbatim.jsonnet | jq .topic_pattern
"^sl1\\.([a-z0-9_-]+)\\.([a-z0-9_-]+)\\.(data)+$"

# Raw output
$ jsonnet test-verbatim.jsonnet | jq -r .topic_pattern
^sl1\.([a-z0-9_-]+)\.([a-z0-9_-]+)\.(data)+$

Alternatively, the multiline construct is usually useful to handle quotes / escape characters in a more "free-form" way:
$ cat test-multiline.jsonnet
{
  // Use rstripChars to remove tail newline from the multiline string
  topic_pattern: std.rstripChars(|||
    ^sl1\.([a-z0-9_-]+)\.([a-z0-9_-]+)\.(data)+$
  |||, '\n'),
}

# Filter field via `jq`
$ jsonnet test-multiline.jsonnet | jq .topic_pattern
"^sl1\\.([a-z0-9_-]+)\\.([a-z0-9_-]+)\\.(data)+$"

# Raw output
$ jsonnet test-multiline.jsonnet | jq -r .topic_pattern
^sl1\.([a-z0-9_-]+)\.([a-z0-9_-]+)\.(data)+$


In Jsonnet, to include a literal backslash \ in the output, you need to escape it with another backslash. Additionally, if you want to avoid the double escaping when dealing with regex in Jsonnet, you can use the raw string syntax by prefixing the string with R and wrapping it in parentheses.
Here's how you can do it:
Using Double Backslashes
This approach results in double backslashes in the output:
{
  topic_pattern: '^sl1\\.([a-z0-9_-]+)\\.([a-z0-9_-]+)\\.(data)+$',
}

Output:
{
  "topic_pattern": "^sl1\\.([a-z0-9_-]+)\\.([a-z0-9_-]+)\\.(data)+$"
}

Using Raw String Syntax
For a cleaner approach that avoids double escaping, use the raw string syntax:
{
  topic_pattern: R'(^sl1.([a-z0-9_-]+).([a-z0-9_-]+).(data)+$)',
}

Output:
{
  "topic_pattern": "^sl1.([a-z0-9_-]+).([a-z0-9_-]+).(data)+$"
}

The raw string syntax (R'...') treats the content inside the parentheses literally, without any need for escaping. This should give you the desired single backslash in the output.

That's the exact same answer chatgpt gave me, and it doesn't work.
